# How to upload a .zip file from remote server to artifactory via Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have this so far but nothing is getting uploaded although it says run successfully

```
node ('node with path to remote server') {
 stage('upload') {
  rtUpload (
  serverId: "artifactoryID",
   spec:"""{
      "files": [
        {
          "pattern": "*.zip",
          "target": "reponame/path/"
        }
     ]
    }"""
  )
 }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: `artifactory-repo` this should contain the name of the artifactory server not the repo-name. By the name of it seems like it is a repo-name and not the artifactory server name you have configured in jenkins

Comment: Its an artifactory id setup on jenkins. Its not a repo..Maybe will be clear if I edit to set it as Artifactory id. That's not causing this issue though, I verified the id set in jenkins. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This warning message introduced in the [Groovy Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin) v2.7.1 at this [commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/commit/a144e59d1c6e4a271b326b15ea53e93f21125ce2#diff-22904a97d5fc051b8c110b932af80293R100). More information can be found in [JENKINS-58643](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58643).
This [Pull Request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/pull/314) should remove this warning.
Does the file uploaded eventually? If it does, you can ignore this message.

By the way, I noticed that you are using scripted pipeline inside declarative pipeline. There is a native [declarative syntax](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax) in Jenkins Artifactory plugin. You can also see a full example [here](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/exclude-patterns-upload-example/Jenkinsfile).

Comment: thank you! no the files are not getting uploaded to artifactory. I have changed the pipeline script above. Now I don't see that error any longer but no files are uploaded to artifactory although it says success.

Comment: Had to use full path for pattern for the files to be found.

Comment: It worked on my machine with relative path. Can you make sure again the 'zip' file exist in the job's workspace directory, 'agent-home/workspaces/workspace-name/' in the agent?